# How can I capture code coverage of manual tests on an Android apk, built with maven?

Tags: android, maven, code-coverage

We're trying to get code coverage analysis of a set of manual tests run on an Android application running on a device.  We build our application using maven, so the cool [emma and ant solution](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/11/obtaining-code-coverage-of-running.html) isn't viable.

Does anybody have explicit experience getting emma or cobertura (or any other open source coverage tool) working for manual testing of Android applications?  We can't afford to purchase a solution (so no Clover, or Java Test Coverage Tool, etc.).